# Permission denied (publickey) with Heroku on Ubuntu

Tags: git, ssh, heroku

I'm getting this error when I try to clone, push, or pull a repository in a brand new Ubuntu VM I'm running. I've deleted and re-added the keys several times with no success.

Here is what I ran:

rails new moo
cd moo
git init
git add .
git commit -m "new app"
heroku create
git push heroku master

I've already tried deleting and re-generating the keys. I'm just using the default names (id_rsa and id_rsa.pub) and overriding the existing ones. And I've cleared and re-added the keys with heroku keys:clear and heroku keys:add

I've seen mention of a config file in ~/.ssh but I don't have one in my folder. Tried creating one with what I thought were valid values with no luck. I don't have an authorized_keys file in there which I've seen mentioned elsewhere.

I've also cleared my .heroku/credentials file and regenerated it. As far as I know, I haven't been using sudo to do anything. This is my first Linux experience...

This all works fine on my Windows machine. I've even regenerated my keys on Windows and re-added them to see if it still works and it does.

Side question: Do I actually need to add my public keys to github.com as the Heroku documentation suggests? I figure adding them to heroku is all that's required since I'm not actually using github to host the code. That said, I *have* added them during my troubleshooting.

Comment: It's working now. I rebooted and it worked. To answer your question: No, I'm not.

Answer (score 0):

Just had this same problem when moving my heroku dev from one computer to another. Something was screwed up with my ssh keys so I removed them from the computer, removed them from heroku, regenerate them on the computer and heroku keys:add the public key back up. Then when I tried heroku git:clone on one of my apps this error message popped up again. I tried going through the same process (thinking I missed something) two times before seeing this article. I restarted my computer and sure enough, I could run the clone.

My guess is that the key is being stored in some session and restarting clears that, but this is just a guess.